# Command substitution does not work in Ubuntu shortcuts

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I want to set a combination of keys as a shortcut, which is possible in Ubuntu through `system settings > keyboard > shortcuts` (may be different, my laptop isn't in English).

The command line to be executed is the following :

```
notify-send "4 stars for «$(rhythmbox-client --set-rating 4 \
--print-playing-format=%tt)»"
```

which works just fine in `gnome-terminal`... But when I set the shortcut, it is executed as if the double quotes were replaced by single quotes, which means that the $(...) part isn't executed and renders as text...

How can I resolve my issue ? Thanks !!

Comment: Try: `sh -c 'notify-send "4 stars for «$(rhythmbox-client --set-rating 4 --print-playing-format=%tt)»"'`, if it didn't worked then paste your code in a file named for example: `bla.sh` then use `bash /path/to/bla` as your command for shortcut.

Comment: Weird, none of both works ! From the terminal it works, but not from the shortcuts.... I wrote `sh -c 'notify-send "'$1' étoiles pour «$(rhythmbox-client --set-rating '$1' --print-playing-format=%tt)»"'` into a file, but it doesn't change anything !!

Comment: Thanks ! Actually, putting it into a file worked, but only if I called a real link like `/home/userName/scriptsFolder/scriptName.sh`. It didn't work before because I wrote a link with `~` for my home folder, but this apparently doesn't work...

Comment: So I sent it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file somewhere you like, e.g `~/script.sh` and add your command into that file, then add your shortcut with a command like this:

```
/bin/bash /home/username/script.sh
```

It should work now.